# delphi xe3 dll injection for 64bit dll to 64bit process doesn't work

Tags: delphi, dll-injection

I'm using this code to inject my 64bit dll into a 64bit process on windows 7 64 bit,CreateRemoteThread return 200  but still the dll does not injected, I tested my dll with another source and it works fine, Process Explorer shows that my code does not work,What can be wrong with this code, I'm using delphi XE3 and i have compile the code on 64bit target platform.

```
function InjectDLL(dwPID: DWORD; DLLPath: pwidechar): integer;
var
dwThreadID: Cardinal;
hProc, hThread, hKernel: NativeUInt;
BytesWritten: NativeUInt;
pRemoteBuffer, pLoadLibrary: Pointer;
begin
try
hProc := OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, dwPID);
if hProc = 0 then
begin
  Result := 0;
  Exit;
end;
pRemoteBuffer := VirtualAllocEx(hProc, nil, Length(DLLPath) + 1, MEM_COMMIT,
  PAGE_READWRITE);
if pRemoteBuffer = nil then
begin
  Result := 0;
  Exit;
end;
if WriteProcessMemory(hProc, Pointer(pRemoteBuffer), lpvoid(DLLPath),
  Length(DLLPath) + 1, BytesWritten) = False then
begin
  Result := 0;
  Exit;
end;
hKernel := GetModuleHandle(pwidechar('kernel32.dll'));
pLoadLibrary := (GetProcAddress(hKernel, pansichar('LoadLibraryA')));
hThread := CreateRemoteThread(hProc, Pointer(nil), 0, Pointer(pLoadLibrary),
  Pointer(pRemoteBuffer), 0, dwThreadID);

WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
VirtualFreeEx(hProc, Pointer(pRemoteBuffer), Length(DLLPath) + 1,
  MEM_RELEASE);
CloseHandle(hThread);
CloseHandle(hProc);
// ShowMessage(IntToStr(hThread)+' '+ inttostr(dwThreadID));
Result := 1;
except
on d: exception do
begin
end;
end;
end;
```

Comment: @hvd I can't see any code here that can raise an exception. These are just a bunch of WinAPI calls which don't raise.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Are you sure about that? I wouldn't be surprised by an `EAccessViolation` exception.

Comment: @hvd Which API call here do you suspect for raising an AV?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I expect `pLoadLibrary` to get set to `nil`, so `CreateRemoteThread` gets a `nil` argument where it shouldn't get one. But thinking about it more, that could only (if it causes an exception at all) cause an exception in the other process, so isn't covered by the except handler in this code. (Ignoring any exceptions is still wrong, though.)

Comment: @hvd Well I agree with that final sentiment. My code strips the exception handler altogether.

Comment: *"CreateRemoteThread return 200 but .."*   > *"Note that CreateRemoteThread may succeed even if lpStartAddress points to data, code, or is not accessible."*

Answer (score 4):

You are calling `LoadLibraryA`, but passing it UTF-16 encoded data. Either switch to `LoadLibraryW` or convert the module name to ANSI.

I would do the former. As well as switching to `LoadLibraryW`, you need to copy the entire buffer. Achieve that by replacing the two instances of `Length(DLLPath) + 1` with `SizeOf(Char)*(Length(DLLPath) + 1)`.

Some more comments:

- Using `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` is excessive. You only need `PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD or PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION or PROCESS_VM_OPERATION or PROCESS_VM_WRITE or PROCESS_VM_READ`.
- The `PAnsiChar` cast in `GetProcAddress(hKernel, pansichar('LoadLibraryA'))` looks wrong. Because `'LoadLibraryA'` is UTF-16 encoded. Just use `GetProcAddress(hKernel, 'LoadLibraryA')`. Or `'LoadLibraryW'` if you go down that route.
- Using `NativeUInt` for handles is wrong. It doesn't actually matter, but you should use `THandle`.
- When using `MEM_RELEASE` you must pass `0` for the size parameter.

Put that all together and the code should look like this:

```
function InjectDLL(dwPID: DWORD; DLLPath: PWideChar): integer;
var
  dwThreadID: Cardinal;
  hProc, hThread, hKernel: THandle;
  BytesToWrite, BytesWritten: SIZE_T;
  pRemoteBuffer, pLoadLibrary: Pointer;
begin
  hProc := OpenProcess(PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD or PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION or PROCESS_VM_OPERATION or PROCESS_VM_WRITE or PROCESS_VM_READ, False, dwPID);
  if hProc = 0 then
    exit(0);
  try
    BytesToWrite := SizeOf(WideChar)*(Length(DLLPath) + 1);
    pRemoteBuffer := VirtualAllocEx(hProc, nil, BytesToWrite, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
    if pRemoteBuffer = nil then
      exit(0);
    try
      if not WriteProcessMemory(hProc, pRemoteBuffer, DLLPath, BytesToWrite, BytesWritten) then
        exit(0);
      hKernel := GetModuleHandle('kernel32.dll');
      pLoadLibrary := GetProcAddress(hKernel, 'LoadLibraryW');
      hThread := CreateRemoteThread(hProc, nil, 0, pLoadLibrary, pRemoteBuffer, 0, dwThreadID);
      try
        WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
      finally
        CloseHandle(hThread);
      end;
    finally
      VirtualFreeEx(hProc, pRemoteBuffer, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
    end;
  finally
    CloseHandle(hProc);
  end;
  exit(1);
end;
```

Personally, I'd probably pass in a `string` rather than a `PWideChar`, but perhaps you have some other motivation for doing that.

Comment: Thanks for your time David,But still same result,I don't know what should  i do, I think the problem caused by Delphi XE compiler,any idea?

Comment: Still same result? You didn't even tell us yet what that result is.

Comment: Hello, can Dll injection works on MAC OS ? (since XE3 is built for cross-platform applications and provide a good OS API abstraction)

Comment: @smarty Hmm, it's a totally different platform. I think you'll need a bespoke solution for Mac.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:Thanks, that's what i guess... but when they said **native multi-platform deployment** i think is a big lie for curious developers, in fact they must  precise what is the re-defenition of **native multi-platform** ...

Comment: @smarty Injection is platform specific. Nobody would expect a x-plat library to somehow encapsulate injection.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, in a dll injection, `LoadLibraryW` is executed initialy on "injector.exe" or already directly in "target.exe"? Because if is already directly in "target.exe", is possible intercept this api from "target.exe" by Api Hooking techniques. I'm right about this affirmation?